# The Collagen Triple Helix

Tags: proteins, amino-acids

In the amino acid sequence X-Hyp-Gly (where X can be any amino acid) of the triple helix can the **Hyp** residue be both hydroxyproline and hydroxylysine? In our textbook it says that the Hyp residue is hydroxyproline but "hydroxylysine also occurs in the collagen".

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. We can answer this question for you, but you will learn more by thinking about the structure of the amino acids and of collagen, and WHY every third residue might be hydroxyproline, and whether the structure of lysine would allow it to perform a similar function. (This is also what we expect of people who post questions.) Look at one of the online texts at NCBI bookshelf — [Lodish](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21582/), and perhaps [this article](https://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/4). Come back and tell us what you found.